# How to access QML Local Storage in both iOS and Android

Tags: qml, local-storage

I want to know what is the best way to data set and get from local storage of mobile devices using QML.

Comment: Did you try to look that in Qt documentation? [Qt Quick Local Storage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-localstorage-qmlmodule.html).

Comment: Yes @folibis I did see, but I want to just save and fetch text, no need sql.. and other thing... is iOS support SQLite ?

Comment: Ok, you can use [Settings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html) item to store known data type values or use simple C++ extension to store a file in writable area. Use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation)` to get that.

Comment: any code sample ?

Comment: Search at this site or Google, there is lots of examples how to do that.

Comment: @folibis Thanks... !